# Rescue ruby command in shell script

Tags: ruby, shell, amazon-ec2

I have a simple sh script (file.command) which connects to an Amazon EC2 instance and afterwards performs a command `twurl....` (in ruby).

```
#!/bin/sh

#Connect to Amazon EC2
ssh -i ~/.ssh/research.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com twurl -t -d track=keyword  -H stream.twitter.com /1.1/statuses/filter.json
```

This command sometimes throws a timeout error. How can I rescue this error so that the command doesn't cancel?

Error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:64:in `rbuf_fill': execution expired (Timeout::Error)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:104:in `read_all'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2228:in `read_body_0'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2181:in `read_body'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/twurl-0.8.3/bin/../lib/twurl/request_controller.rb:14:in `perform_request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1054:in `request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2144:in `reading_body'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1053:in `request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1037:in `request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1035:in `request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/twurl-0.8.3/bin/../lib/twurl/oauth_client.rb:80:in `perform_request_from_options'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/twurl-0.8.3/bin/../lib/twurl/request_controller.rb:13:in `perform_request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/twurl-0.8.3/bin/../lib/twurl/request_controller.rb:9:in `dispatch'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/twurl-0.8.3/bin/../lib/twurl/abstract_command_controller.rb:7:in `dispatch'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/twurl-0.8.3/bin/../lib/twurl/cli.rb:38:in `dispatch'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/twurl-0.8.3/bin/../lib/twurl/cli.rb:21:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/twurl-0.8.3/bin/twurl:4
from /usr/bin/twurl:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/twurl:19
    logout
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

**08/26/2013 EDIT:**

I have written a ruby script which should catch the error, but it seems the method "twurl" isn't recognized in the script, although when running "twurl... " directly on the instance (and not via a script) everything works..

execute_twurl.rb

```
begin
   twurl -t -d track=keyword -H stream.twitter.com /1.1/statuses/filter.json)
rescue Exception=>e
    e.inspect
end
```

called with filename.sh

```
   #!/bin/sh

    #Connect to Amazon EC2
    ssh -i ~/.ssh/research.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com ruby execute_twurl.rb
```

gives Error:

```
execute_twurl.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tUMINUS, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
   twurl -t -d track=keyword -H stre...
             ^
execute_twurl.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
...track=keyword -H stream.twitter.com /1.1/statuses/fil...
                              ^
execute_twurl.rb:2: unknown regexp options - tat
execute_twurl.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND
```

Comment: Write a Ruby script that will make use of twurl. There you can write your custom rescue handling.

Comment: Is the ruby script yours?  Because to catch a ruby exception you either have to rewrite the twurl code, or you have to write a ruby program that executes the twurl program and then catches the exception thrown by twurl.  You can't catch a ruby exception in a shell script.  You can certainly check the exit status of the ssh command in your shell script and re-execute your shell command if the remote command failed.

Comment: The twurl code is not from me - that's the point. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to run system commands within ruby, you can do the following:

```
system 'twurl -t -d track=keyword -H stream.twitter.com /1.1/statuses/filter.json'
```

this gives you the  global variable $? for the exit status of the process which should be 0 if the process didn't succeed.  so your ruby script would be something like:

```
system 'twurl -t -d track=keyword -H stream.twitter.com /1.1/statuses/filter.json'
if $? == 0
   #retry, throw exeption, etc. 
end
```

you can also use backticks to run the command and get output status.  the following may work for the timeout error.

```
output=`twurl -t -d track=keyword -H stream.twitter.com /1.1/statuses/filter.json` ;
result=$?.success?
```

Comment: Your idea would be perfect but it doesn't work.. seems like $? isn't 0 when the execution expires and the timeout::error is thrown..

Comment: I added an option to use backticks that may solve your problem